# Identification of matrix index notation

Tags: notation

I came across this expression in the documentation for some software:

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^c\alpha_{i*(j)k}q_j=Q_k$

Here, $\alpha$ is the element of a matrix with the rather curious index "$i*(j)k$", which the documentation describes as being a mapping function from the elements of one matrix to another.  I have never seen this notation before in my life, specifically the use of the multiplication operator and the parentheses.  I am familiar with Einstein notation for matricies, but this does not seem to be related to that.  It is possible that this is just a typo in the documentation, but in case anyone can make sense of it, please help me understand!  Thanks.

Comment: A further perplexity of that definition is the meaning of "$i$" in there. Is there context for that?

Comment: The software is for analyzing chemical reactions; "$i$" in this case is the index of a chemical element that appears in the reaction.  For example, $i=1$ is carbon, $i=2$ is hydrogen, etc.

Comment: Gotcha. Best I can guess is that they intend it as $\alpha_{i*(j),k}$ i.e. $\alpha$ as an array. But that still leaves the $i*(j)$ mysterious.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that $\alpha$ is a 2D matrix/array, so it definitely needs a comma in there somewhere to denote the two indicies.  I think you're correct in that there's a missing comma.

Comment: I'm guessing the star is there in order to visually separate $a_i$, the array for a particular chemical element, from the indices $j$ and $k$? But this still doesn't explain the parentheses on $(j)$, so who knows...

Comment: I'm emailing the lead developer now.  I'll report back with his response.  BTW, is it uncouth to answer my own question?

Comment: Not at all. In fact, I encourage people to do so when they can.

Comment: I have a guess that it means the $k$th column of $Q$ is given by the matrix-vector product of the matrix $\alpha_i$ with the column vector $q$. If the parenthesis were on the $k$ instead, I think it may have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this obscure notation was invented by the authors of the paper.  In short, there are two vectors $I$ and $J$, and by definition $J$ is a subset of $I$.  Therefore, any element $J_j$ has a corresponding element $I_i$, and the mapping function between these two elements is denoted by "$i*(j)$".  In practice, this is used to say that when the index $j$ is used (such as in the summation in my original post), we can instead map it to a corresponding index $i$ and pull the value of interest from $I$ instead of $J$.

The paper in which I found this is publically available if anyone cares to read it.  It is technical report number AD/A-002 791 by Stanford Research Institute, from March 1974.  The title is "Tiger Computer Program Documentation".  A Google search for the title should give you a link to the report as hosted on www.dtic.mil.  The equation of interest is on page I-B-4, second full paragraph.

Thanks to all who helped.